# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Pls help :)

```
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    Excel.Range range;

    xlApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Base.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);

    range= xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns[1,Type.Missing];
```

Comment: Have you tried range= (Range) xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns[1,Type.Missing]; ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Columns` indexer is typed to return `object` and the variable `range` is typed to `Excel.Range`.  This conversion is not legal (a less specific type to a more specific type).  You need to explicitly cast the result to make the conversion work

```
range = (Excel.Range)(xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns[1,Type.Missing]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You get this exception only if Embed Interop types of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel is set to false. If it is set to true then you will not get this exception

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns[1,Type.Missing];
```

it probably returns object, so you have to cast it to `Excel.Range`

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the problem:

```
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3));
Excel.Range range= (Excel.Range)(xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns[1,Type.Missing]);
```

Just try this. Hope it works for you.